# GRE exam question: Determine which of the following is a random variable.

Tags: random-variables, definition

As I know it,

> *A Random Variable is a variable which represents the outcome of a random experiment*.

**Is this correct?**
.

According to the above definition, the following is not a Random Variable as, in this case, the count is deterministic.

1. > We flip a coin thrice and a random variable $X$  represents the count of the flip.  I.e. $X = 1, 2, 3$.

.

The following is a Random Variable as the total count of Heads in tosses is indeterministic.

2. > We flip a coin thrice and a random variable $X$ represents the total count of Heads in THREE flips.  I.e. $X = 0, 1, 2, 3$.

.

But, what about the following? Is the following an example of a random variable?

3. > We flip a coin thrice and a random variable $X$ represents the probability of occurring Heads in each flip.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space#Random_variables). Why not finding out what it is instead of finding out what it is not?

Comment: Yes, the first is NOT a valid random variable because "the count of the flip", the first flip, the second flip, the third flip, is not a single numerical outcome.  Yes, the number of heads **is** a valid random variable.  For the third one, no, the *probability* of getting a head on each flip.  Assuming a fair coin, it is 1/2 for each flip, not a random number.

Comment: @user247327  A random variable can be degenerated which means that $P(X=c)=1$ or even stronger $X(\omega)=c$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$ where $c$ is a constant. So constant and random do not exclude eachother.

Comment: @Vera, regarding your 1st comment, I don't understand that complex and abstract definition.

Comment: @yahoo.com In *lay* terms, a random variable is a measure assigned to the outcomes of some trial (aka experiment), such that every outcome corresponds to some value.

Comment: Ignoring some technicality, random variable is nothing but a function defined on a sample space. (In particular, there is no randomness in random variable! All the randomness is encoded in the probability law instead. One analogy is that each random variable describes certain procedure or tool that measures a quantity out of each occurrence. For instance, imagine a speed gun.) So both 1 and 2 can be understood as random variables. 3 seemsambiguous to me at best, as there is nothing wrong to consider a random variable with the value $1/8$.

Answer (score 2):

1. Although more often viewed as a constant, technically this *is* a random variable.   It has a *degenerate distribution*; meaning that, in this case, it equals 3 with certainty.   $\mathsf P(X{=}k)=\mathbf 1_{k=3}$.   ie: the probability equals $1$ if $k=3$ or equals $0$ otherwise.
2. A much clearer case; this is a random variable with a binomial distribution. $\mathsf P(X{=}k)= {^3\mathrm C_k} 2^{-3}\mathbf 1_{k\in\{0,1,2,3\}}$
3. This is an event.   It directly describes a set of outcomes of the experiment's sample space, without mapping them to a measure.   $\mathbb P(X)=2^{-3}$ since $X=\{({\sf H,H,H})\}$

Comment: Kindly, add some more explanation to $#3$.  How about $X = 0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}$ ?

Comment: 1. Nope, $X=1,2,3$ indicates that you consider the index of the drawing, not the number of drawings.

Comment: 3. Nope, $X$ is said to be a probability, not a drawing.

Comment: It says $X$ is the count of the drawing.  The *count* of three flips is surely three.

Comment: The probability for heads occuring in each flip is $1/8$.

Comment: That would be the *index*, not the *count*.

Comment: @Vera: this is a contrived interpretation. It's easier to see a non-random variable, taking one of three values.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree with that. Especially because the OP apparantly is in a stage that it can be difficult to keep things apart.

Comment: @Vera: also consider that this doesn't fit with the definition given to the OP. There is nothing random in giving as the outcome of the experiment the drawing number. This is perfectly predictable. It's too early for technicalities.

Comment: @yahoo.com: 3. is absolutely not an event, it is a number (without more information, $1/8$).

Answer (score 0):

Not. A probability is a specific number ($\left(\frac12\right)^3$ in the case of a fair coin).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the *probability* of seeing $n$ heads in the first $n$ coin flips is not a random variable because it is not something that we can *measure* or calculate from the results of the experiment.

The *frequency* of seeing $n$ heads in the first $n$ coin flips is a random variable because we can measure that. But the *probability* of seeing $n$ heads in the first $n$ coin flips can only be determined if we have an a priori model of the coin's behaviour.